# Efficient retrieval of file subset with Git

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to receive a selection of files from a remote Git repository to save bandwidth? For my specific case I'd like to mine the latest C source and header files only. No need for history.

Comment: Do you have already cloned the repository or it would be a fresh start? Are you using any hosting like github that provide api to retrieve files and if so, it would be an option for you?

Comment: Fresh start and from there on a weekly refresh so I would be interested in both ways. Using the API might be an idea. It is slow though and the whole point is to go easy on the service resources. GitHub will be first.

Answer (score 0):

That's called "shallow clone" and you could use it like that:

```
  git clone --depth 1 http://url.com
```

Comment: Yeah but maybe this is not what op asked. What if the repo contains other not interesting big files?

Comment: Exactly. Most C repositories go well over a megabyte while the code is just a few kilobytes.